# What does @objc do under the hood?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I couldn't find anything specific to this in Apple's documentation.

Here is a scenario.

Objective-C class:

```
@implementation Superclass

- (instancetype)init {
    self = [super init];
    [self doSomething];
    return self;
}

- (void)doSomething {
    NSLog(@"\ndoSomething called from Superclass\n");
}

@end
```

Swift subclass:

```
class Subclass: Superclass {

    override init() {
        super.init()
        doSomething()
    }

    @objc func doSomething() {
        print("\n\ndoSomething called from Subclass\n")
    }

}
```

Using `@objc` in the method signature of `doSomething` in the subclass causes the method in the superclass never to be called i.e. only `doSomething called from Subclass` is printed to the console.

Removing `@objc` fixes the issue.

Why is this?

Comment: This explains most of your question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24002369/how-to-call-objective-c-code-from-swift

Comment: You can read here: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Attributes.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@objc` makes the method available to the Objective-C runtime,
compare [Attributes](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Attributes.html) in the Swift Language Reference.
Therefore

```
@objc func doSomething()
```

*overrides* the

```
- (void)doSomething
```

instance method defined in the Objective-C superclass. Consequently, if `self` is an instance of `Subclass` then

```
[self doSomething];
```

calls the subclass method – no matter *where* that call is done.
(Message dispatching is fully dynamic in Objective-C.)
That's why the subclass method is called twice.

Without `@objc`, the Swift instance method is not visible to Objective-C,
and does not override the superclass method.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It's good to know that @objc will override the superclass method. I'm wondering if there is any documentation on this? 

Comment: The @objc attribute is documented in the link in my answer. Objective-C messaging is documented here: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithObjects/WorkingwithObjects.html.

Answer (score 0):

When @objc used for class declaration means that you write Objective-C class with Swift.

@objc used for method declaration means that instead of swift's `String`, `Dictionary`, `Notification` etc. actually will be use Objective-C's `NSString`, `NSDictionary`, `NSNotification` and methods become available in Objective-C code.